# Ĉu oni povas uzi la vortojn "maleta", "malolda", "malfrida"?

Tags: word-usage, word-formation, adjectives, antonyms

Mi lernis ke oni povas konstrui vortojn uzanta la prefikso "mal" por esprimi la malon de la vortoj sen la prefikso:

- *granda* ⇒ *malgranda*
- *varma* ⇒ *malvarma*
- *juna* ⇒ *maljuna*

Sed, ĉu oni povas uzi la saman sistemon kun vortoj kiel:

- *eta* ⇒ *maleta*
- *frida* ⇒ *malfrida*
- *olda* ⇒ *malolda*

Mi ne trovis tiujn vortojn en tekstaro.

Se tio ne eblas, kial?

Kiu decidis, ke oni povas uzi la paron "granda" / "malgranda" sed ne "eta" / "maleta"?

Ĉu estas nur kutimo?

Answer (score 4):

Certe eblas uzi ilin sed verŝajne ĝi iel frapus la leganton.

Plejparte ĉar, kvankam oni povas teorie uzi la prefiksojn kaj sufiksojn ie ajn, estas limigita kvanto de paroj kiuj fakte rolas kiel memstaraj vortoj, kaj ili estas pro tio aŭtomate kaj senpere komprenataj de la aŭskultanto/leganto.

Oni povas percepti tion en la fakto ke vortoj kiel "maljunaj" fakte havas memstaran difinon (sub la rubriko de la radiko) en vortaroj kiel [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/jun.html#jun.mal0a):

> **maljuna**: Atingita sian maljunecon

Eĉ povus okazi ke tiuj konataj kombinaĵoj havas subtilajn nuancojn kiuj ne estas koneblaj nur per la logika konekto al la radiko. Kiel ĉiam la signifo de iu vorto estas fando de multaj aferoj, inter kiuj estas la historio de diversaj kuntekstoj en kiuj la vorto uziĝis, kaj kutmetita vorto povas havi sian propran historion, sendependan de la radiko.

Tio ĉi iom similas ankaŭ la uzon de radiko kiu kutime havas unu gramatikan rolon, porokaze en alia rolo. Ekzemple, la difino de "hundi" (kompare la pli kutiman "hundo") estas nebula kaj malferma al libera interpreto laŭ la kunteksto.

Por reiri al via ekzemplo, se iu anstataŭe uzus, ekzemple, "malolda" anstataŭ la pli kutima "juna", mi komprenus la senson, sed mi demandus min "kial oni uzis tie tiun vorton?" -- povus esti ke en la kunteksto (poezio aŭ simile) tio estus la celata efiko. Tamen, se ne, tiaj vortoj estus plejparte evitindaj laŭ mi.

Answer (score 1):

Teorie oni povas uzi tiajn vortojn, sed oni (preskaŭ) neniam faras tion.

Answer (score 1):

Kial ne? Ja en cxiu lingvo ekzistas sinonimoj. La eblecoj esprimi sin en Esperanto estas senlimaj... Tio kontribuas al la ricxeco de nia lingvo, malgraux gxia simpleco. Esperanto estas artefarita kaj cxiu uzanto mem "faras" gxin siaplacxe (laux la reguloj).